# 3 dimensional matrices

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D 4-by-4-by-4 matrix and I consider it circular (so a 4th element of row closes with the 1st and same goes for columns and pages).

we know that in 3D each point has exactly 26 neighbors which can be stated as (i, j, k-1) (i, j, k+1) etc. but I am not sure how to make matlab know that a (i,j, k-1) neighbor of a point (1,1,1) is not (1,1,0) but (as it is circular) (1,1,4) as well as that point (2,4,3)'s neighbor (i,j+1,k) is not (2,5,3) but (2,1,3). In other words HOW DO I MAKE IT CIRCULAR?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB does not have built-in facilities for this, but you can use the `mod` (modulus) function when accessing your matrix to achieve the effect you want. To illustrate this on a vector:

```
v=[1 2 3];
i=5;
result=v(mod(i-1, length(v))+1);
% assigns 2 to 'result'
```

You'll probably want to write a function that encapsulates the "circular" matrix access so that you have to do the index computations in only one place.

Comment: ok, so you're basically saying that I have to modulate it with 4 in my case and than it will automatically treat 0 as 4 and 5 as 1.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Because MATLAB's indexing is one-based, you also need the '-1' and '+1' in addition to the modulus (as shown in my code).

Comment: Thanks, Hvala, Grazie, Danke, Merci!

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the [MOD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mod.html) function as [@MartinB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621883/3-dimensional-matrices/6622160#6622160) explained. Here some code to efficiently compute the neighbors of each point in your 4x4x4 cube:

```
%# generate X/Y/Z coordinates of each point of the 4x4x4 cube
sz = [4 4 4];                            %# size of the cube along each dimension
[X Y Z] = ndgrid(1:sz(1),1:sz(2),1:sz(3));
coords = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)];

%# generate increments to get the 26 neighbors around a 3D point
[X Y Z] = ndgrid([-1 0 1], [-1 0 1], [-1 0 1]);
nb = [X(:) Y(:) Z(:)];
nb(ismember(nb,[0 0 0],'rows'),:) = [];  %# remove the row [0 0 0]

%# for each 3D point, compute its neighbors
allNeighbors = zeros([size(nb,1) 3 size(coords,1)]);
szMod = repmat(sz, [size(nb,1) 1]);
for i=1:size(coords,1)
    cc = bsxfun(@plus, nb, coords(i,:)); %# find 26 neighbors of coords(i,:)
    cc = mod(cc-1,szMod)+1;              %# wrap around circularly

    allNeighbors(:,:,i) = cc;            %# save them for later processing
end
```

The order of the neighbors generated is as follows:

```
>> nb
nb =
    -1    -1    -1      %# read as: (i-1,j-1,k-1)
     0    -1    -1      %# read as: (i,j-1,k-1)
     1    -1    -1      %# ...
    -1     0    -1
     0     0    -1
     1     0    -1
    -1     1    -1
     0     1    -1
     1     1    -1
    -1    -1     0
     0    -1     0
     1    -1     0
    -1     0     0
     1     0     0
    -1     1     0
     0     1     0
     1     1     0
    -1    -1     1
     0    -1     1
     1    -1     1
    -1     0     1
     0     0     1
     1     0     1
    -1     1     1
     0     1     1
     1     1     1
```