# How to draw a filled circle on a video frame using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have an "inverted-pendulum" video which I try to find the mid point of moving part. I am using Computer Vision Toolbox

[image]

I change the mid point's color using detected coordinates. Assume that `X` is the frame's row number for the detected mid point and the `Y` is the col number.

```
while ~isDone(hVideoFileReader)

    frame = step(hVideoFileReader);
    ...
    frame(X-3:X+3, Y-3:Y+3, 1) = 1; % # R=1 make the defined region red
    frame(X-3:X+3, Y-3:Y+3, 2) = 0; % # G=0
    frame(X-3:X+3, Y-3:Y+3, 3) = 0; % # B=0

    step(hVideoPlayer, frame);

end
```

Then I easily have a red square. But I want to add a red filled circle on the detected point, instead of  a square. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Dima, I have created a shapeInserter object.

```
greenColor = uint8([0 255 0]); 
hFilledCircle = vision.ShapeInserter('Shape','Circles',...
                              'BorderColor','Custom',...
                              'CustomBorderColor', greenColor ,...
                              'Fill', true, ...
                              'FillColor', 'Custom',...
                              'CustomFillColor', greenColor );
...

fc = int32([Y X 7;]);

frame = step(hFilledCircle, frame, fc);
```

I then applied it to detected point.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`insertShape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/insertshape.html) function. Example:

```
img = imread('peppers.png');
img = insertShape(img, 'FilledCircle', [150 280 35], ...
    'LineWidth',5, 'Color','blue');
imshow(img)
```

The position parameter is specified as `[x y radius]`

[image]

---

### EDIT:

Here is an alternative where we manually draw the circular shape (with transparency):

```
% some RGB image
img = imread('peppers.png');
[imgH,imgW,~] = size(img);

% circle parameters
r = 35;                    % radius
c = [150 280];             % center
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, 50); % approximate circle with 50 points

% create a circular mask
BW = poly2mask(r*cos(t)+c(1), r*sin(t)+c(2), imgH, imgW);

% overlay filled circular shape by using the mask
% to fill the image with the desired color (for all three channels R,G,B)
clr = [0 0 255];            % blue color
a = 0.5;                    % blending factor
z = false(size(BW));
mask = cat(3,BW,z,z); img(mask) = a*clr(1) + (1-a)*img(mask);
mask = cat(3,z,BW,z); img(mask) = a*clr(2) + (1-a)*img(mask);
mask = cat(3,z,z,BW); img(mask) = a*clr(3) + (1-a)*img(mask);

% show result
imshow(img)
```

I'm using the `poly2mask` function from Image Processing Toolbox to create the circle mask (idea from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856392/97160)). If you don't have access to this function, here is an alternative:

```
[X,Y] = ndgrid((1:imgH)-c(2), (1:imgW)-c(1));
BW = (X.^2 + Y.^2) < r^2;
```

That way you get a solution using core MATLAB functions only (no toolboxes!)

Comment: is `insertShape` MATALB 2014's function? I use 2012

Comment: ah, `insertShape` was introduced in R2013a: http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013a/vision/release-notes.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have an older version of MATLAB with the Computer Vision System Toolbox installed, you can use `vision.ShapeInserter` system object.

Comment: I knew it was [there](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2012a/toolbox/vision/ref/vision.shapeinserterclass.html) :) It was even available back when it was part of the Simulink toolbox "Video and Image Processing Blockset" (which later became the current CVST toolbox as of R2011a):  http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/drawshapes.html